# How to enforce in-place member construction for non-aggregate classes?

Tags: c++

Sometimes I hope to enforce in-place construction of some members in a class(especially a non-aggregate one), for possible efficiency gain, or for a sense of certainty("I have control over what it does").

However, I cannot manage to do so. The problem is illustrated in the following attempt to implement a scope guard.

A trivial implementation will be like this. I hope to hide `_func` and `_exec`, and disable copy/move construction/assignment, so an aggregate is not an option.

```cpp
template<class F>
class [[nodiscard]] at_scope_exit {
    F _func;
    bool _exec = true;
public:
    at_scope_exit(F&& f)noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<F>):_func{ std::move(f) } {}
    void disable()noexcept { _exec = false; }
    at_scope_exit(const at_scope_exit&) = delete;
    at_scope_exit& operator=(const at_scope_exit&) = delete;
    ~at_scope_exit() {
        if (_exec) { _func(); }
    }
};

void useit() {
    int i = 1;
    at_scope_exit atexit{ [&] {i--; } };
}
```

It works fine in most cases. However, it cannot guarantee in-place construction.

```cpp
struct bad_closure {
    ~bad_closure() { std::cout << "~bad_closure()"; }
    void operator()() { std::cout << "operator()"; }
};

void problem() {
    at_scope_exit atexit{ bad_closure{} };
    //output: ~bad_closure()operator()~bad_closure()
}
```

Leaving aside wether we should use something like `bad_closure` in practice, this possibility of construct-then-move pattern makes me uncomfortable.(In this certain case, it seems the compiler is not allowed to do copy elision) How can I eliminate this possibility?

How should I modify `at_scope_exit` to be able to write down the following code, ***without worrying about an extra copy/move on construction?***

```cpp
void expected() {
    struct foo { ~foo() { std::cout << "~foo()"; } };
    int i = 1;
    at_scope_exit atexit{ [&i,f = foo{}] { i = 0; } };
    /*
    required output:
    ~foo()
    */
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't. C++17 requires that two objects are created with `B`: the temporary, then a reference is bound to the temporary (invoking temporary materialization), and finally a field is created via move construction. No move elision allowed here. Your only option is to make sure you don't do anything in the destructor (including debug output) so the compiler can optimize via the "as-if" rule.

Comment: On second thought, I may be wrong and move elision is allowed here. Not sure.

Comment: there is no reason to provide an empty `operator()`, either it actually do the work and you pass it to scope guard, or you use it directly as scope guard. mixing the 2 only give you trouble. (and `closure`/`foo` doesn't comply with rule of 3/5, which is also part of the problem)

Comment: I've edited the description. The question is more focused now.

Comment: What happens if you transfer `f` by value?

Comment: @Red.Wave take `expected()` for example, I will get "~foo()~foo()~foo()" if I transfer by value. "~foo()~foo()" if by F&&.

Comment: Your closure should be (nearly) free to move, so you shouldn't care much whether the move is elided or not. Copying is another matter, just don't let it be copied.

Comment: Move is supposed to be ligth-weight (when available), and destruction of a moved-from object shall be as close to noop as possible. Direct initialization is an optimization, forced on some occasions, allowed where possible. Don't complicate your design for such premature micro-optimizations; you may end-up with surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get copy/move elision with aggregate initialization, not with a constructor call.

While you can't declare the copy/move special members functions as `delete`d in an aggregate class, you can enforce that the implicitly-declared member functions are defined as `delete`d or not declared at all by adding a member that is not copyable/movable.

For example:

```
struct non_movable {
    non_movable() = default;
    non_movable(const non_movable&) = delete;
    non_movable& operator=(const non_movable&) = delete;
};

template<class F>
struct [[nodiscard]] at_scope_exit {
    F _func;

    class _exec_class : non_movable {
        bool _value = true;
        friend at_scope_exit;
    } _exec{};

    void disable() noexcept { _exec._value = false; }
    ~at_scope_exit() {
        if (_exec._value) { _func(); }
    }
};
```

This way it is also impossible for a user to access the `_exec` value.

However, it is still possible for a user to access the `_func` object. I don't think there is any way to avoid this while still maintaining aggregate initialization. Copy/move elision does anyway imply that the object is constructed in the context of the caller, so it has full control over it.

---

The other alternative is to not pass the `_func` object directly, but instead to pass only information needed to construct the object and then in-place construct it in a constructor of `at_scope_exit`.

But that only makes sense if passing that information would be cheaper than passing the object itself or if `F` isn't copyable/movable.

In your examples copying/moving the lambdas is cheap and there is probably no actual cost in the generated code if it weren't for your output in the destructor which the compiler is not allowed to remove. Regardless of copy/move elision rules the compiler is always allowed to optimize in any way as long as the observable behavior doesn't change. There wouldn't be any observable behavior difference between doing the copy of `closure` and not doing it if it weren't for the output in the destructor.

There are three ways to achieve this that I can think of:

1. A constructor for `at_scope_exit` which takes a variadic number of arguments and perfectly-forwards them to in-place construct the `F` object:

   ```
    template<typename... Args>
    at_scope_exit(Args&&... args) : _func(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
   ```
2. A constructor for `at_scope_exit` which takes a callable that produces the object:

   ```
    template<std::invocable_r<F> U>
    at_scope_exit(U&& u) : _func(std::invoke(std::forward<U>(u))) { }
   ```
3. A constructor for `at_scope_exit` which takes an object that can be converted to `F`:

   ```
    template<std::convertible_to<F> U>
    at_scope_exit(U&& u) : _func(static_cast<F>(std::forward<U>(u))) { }
   ```

These all have various pros and cons.

In cases 1. and 3. the user would need to provide the type `F` explicitly, while it would be possible to write a deduction guide for 2. that will still allow for CTAD to work.

Probably, in all cases, it would make sense to add a another parameter as a tag to allow the simple copying/moving constructor to still be used and clearly distinguished and so that the constructors aren't used as copy/move-like constructors.

(I am assuming C++20 or later.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The first version you show seems the best reach for now without breaking the promise of in-place construction. So, in current state of C++, if I have a private member lambda with capture, then I just cannot enforce in-place construction while still keeping an easy usage pattern...

Comment: @firlas I think that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using C++17 or later.

For your first case, you are passing a prvalue to `_func`, which requires [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for compiler.

And the second case. In your constructor of `at_scope_exit_class`, you bind it to a rvalue reference(`f`). And your deconstructor of `closure` has observable side-effect. This prevents compiler from optimizing.

For your question, your `closure` should have constructor and deconstructor without any observable side-effect. And the compiler will be able to optimize.